# Prove or disprove that $2^{\frac{\pi}{2}}$ is an irrational number.

Tags: irrational-numbers

#### Problem

Prove or disprove that $2^{\frac{\pi}{2}}$ is an irrational number.

#### My Try

According to our mathematical intuition, we may want to apply **Gelfond–Schneider theorem**, which states that

> if $\alpha,\beta$ are two algebraic numbers, where $\alpha$ dose not
> equal $0$ or $1$ and $\beta$ is not a rational number, then
> $\alpha^\beta$ is a transcendental number.

But in fact, it can't work here, because $\beta=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ here is not an **algebraic number** at all, which doesn't satisfy the premise of the theorem.

Besides, I have tested this on WolframAlpha. It outputs the consequence as follows

[image]

Now, how to go on?

Comment: What is the source of this problem? There are tricks that can sometimes be applied to problems like this (e.g. we can prove that irrationality of $e^\pi$), but I don't see anything that would clearly apply in this instance...

Comment: Oh, this problem doesn't need any particular source, Maybe, it naturally comes from our mathematical thinking?

Comment: Related: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Is_2_to_the_power_of_Pi_Rational%3F

Comment: @mengdie1982 The way the question was phrased when I initially wrote my reply was 'prove that $2^{\pi/2}$ is irrational', suggesting that you were being asked to find a proof; that, and the seemingly-arbitrary choice of $\pi/2$ rather than $\pi$ in the exponent, are why I asked to the source, because AFAIK (and as Michael's link suggests) the problem is open. If you were inquiring about the status, then I would suggest a title along the lines of 'Is it known whether $2^{\pi/2}$ is rational or not?'

Comment: @Michael You mean this is a pendent problem? But the rationality or irrationality of $2^{\pi}$ seems not to imply anything on my problem.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki yes,sir... I have revised my title, only because I'm not sure that it's really an irrational number.

Comment: @mengdie1982: Surely if $2^\pi$ is irrational then so is $\sqrt{2^\pi}=2^{\pi/2}$.

Comment: In a similar spirit @HenningMakholm if $2^{\pi/2}$ was known to be rational then $2^{\pi}$ would be rational. So, if it is known what $2^{\pi/2} $ is then it must be irrational.

Comment: If it were rational, we would have $\pi=\frac{2(\ln p - \ln q)}{\ln 2}$. Maybe there are some theorems that $\pi$ cannot have this form?

Comment: @SK19 It is unknown if $2^{\pi}$ is irrational or rational.

Comment: @clark Yes, people have noted. I don't know about you, but just because something is unproven doesn't mean I can't try.

Comment: @SK19 bless your heart brother, just wanted to make sure in case you missed it. Side note: I have spent a lot of time, in the past, trying to solve Goldbach's conjecture, so I can relate.

Comment: @SK19 You're welcome to try, but this is not the kind of problem that will get a one-line (or even one-page) proof.

Comment: Taking $2^\pi = e^{\pi\ln(2)}$, i.e. three transcendental numbers. Are there any theorems on this? For example instinctively, $\pi\ln(2)$ seems like it might also be transcendental (it is certainly irrational if that is enough). I should point out that I am not really well equipped to tackle this. Just tossing ideas around.

Comment: @Jepsilon: Unfortunately that's the opposite knowledge of what would be useful. If $\pi \ln(2)$ happened to be _rational_ (or even algebraic) then the Lindemann-Weierstrass theorem would tell us that $2^\pi$ is transcendental, but if $\pi\ln(2)$ is transcendental, we're no further. **Do** you know that $\pi\ln(2)$ is irrational, though? It's not obvious to me. (Multiplying the Leibniz series and the alternating harmonic series _might_ give something that's nice enough to work with. But since they're only conditionally convergent, multiplying term by term is not automatically valid).

Comment: For $\pi \ln(2)$ I reasoned that since transcendental numbers are defined to be such that you cannot get to a rational using any finite number of algebraic operations, then them being transcendental would not set the condition for their product to be rational. Is this wrong?

Comment: @Jepsilon that's not an easy question. For instance it is not known if $\pi\cdot e$ or $\pi+e$ are irrational or not. How, can we distinguish $\pi\cdot e$  from the case $\pi \cdot \pi^{-1}$?

Comment: @clark oh ok I see what you mean now

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comment section, the irrationality of $2^\pi$ is unknown, so is that of $2^{\pi/2}$.